# Get last array in array of arrays

Tags: javascript

So I have a dynamically generated array and essentially all of the arrays except the last needs to be deleted so I can just the values from the last array into an aggregation with some other data

Consider a structure something like this:

```
let target  = []
let data = [ 
[ { name: 'something',
      total: 100,
      number: 100,
      category: 'smh' } ],
  [ { name: 'something',
      total: 200,
      number: 200,
      category: 'smh' } ] 
]
let arrLength = data.length
target.push(data.splice(0, arrLength, -1))
```

The last element will always be all of the entries in my array aggregated,

So my question is how do I ensure I always push the last ARRAY to the target-array so I get only the data that is an aggregation of the previous ones?

desired result

```
[ { name: 'something',
      total: 200,
      number: 200,
      category: 'smh' } ]
```

Comment: please add the wanted result of all variables.

Comment: `target.push(data.pop())`?

Comment: @adiga it is array of objects so no I have already tried this

Comment: @nina I will modify my post

Comment: If the last array always has one object then, `target.push(data.pop()[0])`. If you have multiple objects in the last array and you want all of them in the `target` array: `target.push(...data.pop())`

Answer (score 1):

To push the last one simply use this:

```
target.push(data[data.length - 1]);
```

Comment: Would be correct if I only needed the last element in the array but in this case I need the last array in the array

Comment: What...? if you have an array of arrays, the last element itself is an array